# Usage of 'run something down south'

Tags: phrase-usage

I have the following sentence which describes a person putting a finger on someone's chest and ***trailing it downwards***:

- She put a finger lightly on my chest and then **ran it down south**.

In this context, would it be correct to use ***run something down south*** or should it be replaced with ***trailed it downwards***?

- She put a finger lightly on my chest and then **trailed it downwards**.

If *south* can mean *lower part of the body* then I can definitely see the first example working too. I haven't found any examples of this occurring so probably such definition of the word *south* does not exist.

Comment: They’re both grammatical and idiomatic. From a writing style perspective though, they’re a little kitschy in the pulp romance novel or fanfic sense.

Comment: I do not find it idiomatic. In context I understood what it meant, but to me it is a (not very effective) one-off metaphor in this sense.

Comment: @WeatherVane I recognise the expression "north of $100" but it seems specifically American English to me; it isn't used much on this side of the pond. However I think that speakers of most English dialects would both recognise and use  "everything's been going south since I turned 60" meaning that one's body has been deteriorating since that time. That does, of course, have the implication that the body is generally sagging.

Comment: “Ran it south” is more idiomatic than “ran it down south.” Down south, up north, down east are more indicative of location, at least in AmE. South is down, north is up, metaphorically.

Comment: @Xanne I think that's false. First of all, "down east" is not idiomatic. Secondly, we are talking about location, just not cardinal directional location. "Go down" and "Go down south" have been used interchangeably for a long time.

Comment: Definition for *down south* [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down%20south).

Based on this, it could be deduced that *down south* can mean *lower part* of everything based on the previous comments.